# Why do I keep getting errors when I try to install PySide6 on windows PC?

Tags: python, pip, pyside6

I have been trying to install PySide6 on my PC (Windows 10 64bits) with Python 3.9.0 installed, but I keep getting errors every time.

I used the command pip install PySide6 It is not working for me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyside2 (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyside2
```

Comment: try with python3.8 64 bits

Answer (score 1):

#### At the time of writing:

The problem is that most of the binaries are not yet compatible and are not yet compiled for Python 3.9 at the time of writing. If you want the best compatibility, use Python 3.7 or Python 3.8. Most of the packages have been compiled for Python 3.8 but not many for Python 3.9.

#### For the future people that come here:

I would recommend you to keep one minor version behind the current stable release to not face dependency problems as the above section explains.

For Example:

If current stable release is Python 3.12 then you should install Python 3.11 or Python 3.10. Just one or two versions behind the current stable release.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you Python installation is `64 bit` and not `32 bit`. It has an impact on compatible and thus available binaries.